# SQL Server 2008 Using while loop to populate missing values

Tags: sql-server-2008

This is my table as is:

[image: table as is]

For each instance of Patient Arrive, I need an instance of the other status. As you can see in this particular scenario, I have 3 patient arrive input; therefore, my status should be as follow table 2:

[image: table should be]

Here's what I have done so far.

```
DECLARE @Patient_Leave TABLE 
                 (
                     id     INT,
                     status     VARCHAR (200)
      ,times     VARCHAR (200)

     )
      DECLARE  @arrive INT = 0
        DECLARE  @Leave INT 

          set @Patient_Leave = (select ((select COUNT(status) FROM Parameters VF WITH (NOLOCK) where status ='Patient Arrive) -
           (select COUNT(status) FROM Parameters VF WITH (NOLOCK) where status='Patient leave')))

              WHILE ( @arrive )  < @Leave

                BEGIN
                  INSERT INTO @Patient_Leave

                    select distinct id, status, (select 'No data entered')as Time FROM Parameters VF WITH (NOLOCK) where status='Patient Leave

                         SET  @arrive =  @arrive + 1

                 END

                   SELECT * FROM @Patient_Leave

                          GO
```

Comment: Your `INSERT INTO` variable appears to be pointing to `@Patient_Leave` which is not a table. Your table was specified as `@PREPPED`. Also, no need for `(select 'no data entered')` as you can just put `'no data entered'`

Comment: it should be @Patient_Leave instead of prepped.

Comment: You have the @Patient_Leave is declared as an integer and therefore not a table and insertable. The preceeding line after insert is a select statement for 3 columns and not returning a single integer

Comment: This query is working; patient_leave is a just a variable to hold a value, but you are right.  I will fix to avoid the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bethony,

I've build the following based off your provided data and tested to success.

SQL Code:

```
USE SO_Tests
GO

--CREATE TABLE Patient_Table
--  (
--      id INT
--      ,status VARCHAR (200)
--      ,times VARCHAR(200)
--     )

TRUNCATE TABLE Patient_Table

INSERT INTO
    Patient_Table
        (ID, status, times)
VALUES
    (123666,'Patient Arrive', '20180606 10:52')
    ,(123666,'Patient Arrive', '20180606 11:21')
    ,(123666,'Patient Arrive', '20180606 11:45')
    ,(123666,'Patient Prepped', '20180606 10:52')
    ,(123666,'Patient Prepped', '20180606 11:45')
    ,(123666,'Patient Leave', '20180606 10:52')
    ,(123666,'Patient Return', '20180606 10:55')
    ,(123666,'Patient Return', '20180606 12:30')
    ,(123666,'Patient Ready', '20180606 12:45')
    ,(123666,'Patient Discharged', '20180606 12:45')

SELECT * FROM Patient_Table

DECLARE @Count_Arrive INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Patient_Table WHERE status = 'Patient Arrive')
DECLARE @Count_Leave INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Patient_Table WHERE status = 'Patient Leave')
DECLARE @Count_Prepped INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Patient_Table WHERE status = 'Patient Prepped')
DECLARE @Count_Return INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Patient_Table WHERE status = 'Patient Return')
DECLARE @Count_Discharged INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Patient_Table WHERE status = 'Patient Discharged')
DECLARE @Count_Ready INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Patient_Table WHERE status = 'Patient Ready')

WHILE(@Count_Arrive <> @Count_Leave OR @Count_Arrive <> @Count_Prepped OR @Count_Arrive <> @Count_Return OR @Count_Arrive <> @Count_Discharged OR @Count_Arrive <> @Count_Ready)
BEGIN

    IF (@Count_Arrive <> @Count_Leave)
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO 
        Patient_Table
    SELECT
        123456,
        'Patient Leave',
        'No Data Provided'

    SET @Count_Leave = @Count_Leave + 1
    END

    IF (@Count_Arrive <> @Count_Prepped)
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO 
        Patient_Table
    SELECT
        123456,
        'Patient Prepped',
        'No Data Provided'

    SET @Count_Prepped = @Count_Prepped + 1
    END

    IF (@Count_Arrive <> @Count_Return)
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO 
        Patient_Table
    SELECT
        123456,
        'Patient Return',
        'No Data Provided'

    SET @Count_Return = @Count_Return + 1
    END

    IF (@Count_Arrive <> @Count_Discharged)
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO 
        Patient_Table
    SELECT
        123456,
        'Patient Discharged',
        'No Data Provided'

    SET @Count_Discharged = @Count_Discharged + 1
    END

    IF (@Count_Arrive <> @Count_Ready)
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO 
        Patient_Table
    SELECT
        123456,
        'Patient Ready',
        'No Data Provided'

    SET @Count_Ready = @Count_Ready + 1
    END


END

SELECT * FROM Patient_Table ORDER BY STATUS
```

Results: [image: Query Results]

This covers the additional statuses where needed and applies dummy rows to the count of the arrival rows

**UPDATE:**
Added in the cursor to progress through the Patient ID's and added some additional handling to prevent adding lines that were never originally recorded and avoiding infinite loop if another status has more row than Patient_Arrive has per id

```
USE SO_Tests
GO

DECLARE @Patient_Table TABLE
  (
      id INT
      ,status VARCHAR (200)
      ,times VARCHAR(200)
     )

--TRUNCATE TABLE Patient_Table

--INSERT INTO
--    Patient_Table
--        (ID, status, times)
--VALUES
--    (123666,'Patient Arrive', '20180606 10:52')
--    ,(123666,'Patient Arrive', '20180606 11:21')
--    ,(123666,'Patient Arrive', '20180606 11:45')
--    ,(123666,'Patient Prepped', '20180606 10:52')
--    ,(123666,'Patient Prepped', '20180606 11:45')
--    ,(123666,'Patient Leave', '20180606 10:52')
--    ,(123666,'Patient Return', '20180606 10:55')
--    ,(123666,'Patient Return', '20180606 12:30')
--    ,(123666,'Patient Ready', '20180606 12:45')
--    ,(123666,'Patient Discharged', '20180606 12:45')



INSERT INTO @Patient_Table SELECT * FROM Patient_Table

DECLARE @id INT

DECLARE Patient_Cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT
        id
    FROM
        @Patient_Table

OPEN Patient_Cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM Patient_Cursor INTO @id
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Count_Arrive INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Patient_Table WHERE status = 'Patient Arrive' AND id = @id)
    DECLARE @Count_Leave INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Patient_Table WHERE status = 'Patient Leave' AND id = @id)
    DECLARE @Count_Prepped INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Patient_Table WHERE status = 'Patient Prepped' AND id = @id)
    DECLARE @Count_Return INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Patient_Table WHERE status = 'Patient Return' AND id = @id)
    DECLARE @Count_Discharged INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Patient_Table WHERE status = 'Patient Discharged' AND id = @id)
    DECLARE @Count_Ready INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Patient_Table WHERE status = 'Patient Ready' AND id = @id)

    WHILE((@Count_Arrive > @Count_Leave and @Count_Leave > 0) OR (@Count_Arrive > @Count_Prepped and @Count_Prepped > 0) OR (@Count_Arrive > @Count_Return and @Count_Return = 0) OR (@Count_Arrive > @Count_Discharged and @Count_Discharged > 0) OR (@Count_Arrive > @Count_Ready and @Count_Ready > 0))
    BEGIN
    print 'recursing'
    print @count_arrive
    print @count_leave
    print @count_prepped
    print @count_return
    print @count_discharged
    print @count_ready

        IF (@Count_Arrive > @Count_Leave and @Count_Leave > 0)
        BEGIN
        INSERT INTO 
            @Patient_Table
        SELECT
            @id,
            'Patient Leave',
            'No Data Provided'

        SET @Count_Leave = @Count_Leave + 1
        END

        IF (@Count_Arrive > @Count_Prepped and @Count_Prepped > 0)
        BEGIN
        INSERT INTO 
            @Patient_Table
        SELECT
            @id,
            'Patient Prepped',
            'No Data Provided'

        SET @Count_Prepped = @Count_Prepped + 1
        END

        IF (@Count_Arrive > @Count_Return and @Count_Return > 0)
        BEGIN
        INSERT INTO 
            @Patient_Table
        SELECT
            @id,
            'Patient Return',
            'No Data Provided'

        SET @Count_Return = @Count_Return + 1
        END

        IF (@Count_Arrive > @Count_Discharged and @Count_Discharged > 0)
        BEGIN
        INSERT INTO 
            @Patient_Table
        SELECT
            @id,
            'Patient Discharged',
            'No Data Provided'

        SET @Count_Discharged = @Count_Discharged + 1
        END

        IF (@Count_Arrive > @Count_Ready and @Count_Ready > 0)
        BEGIN
        INSERT INTO 
            @Patient_Table
        SELECT
            @id,
            'Patient Ready',
            'No Data Provided'

        SET @Count_Ready = @Count_Ready + 1
        END

    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM Patient_Cursor INTO @id

END
SELECT * FROM Patient_Table
SELECT * FROM @Patient_Table
```

Comment: @Bethony, Edited for your ease. You will need to put in something to handle the individualised patient ID's though as this is tested on a single patient

Comment: would an aggregate function handles the individualissed patient? You have given me a big boost.Thanks!

Comment: You could apply a cursor around this calling a list of Patient ID's and then pushing each ID individually into the above count collectors and inserts.

Comment: It runs forever(infinit loop). when i stop the query I am getting the following printout:    (9 row(s) affected)
recursing
3
1
2
2
1
0

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)
recursing
3
2
3
3
2
0

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)
recursing
3
1
2
2
1
0

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)
recursing
3
2
3
3
2
0

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)
recursing

Comment: It worked when added select DISTINCT id. however, I am not get result for status who's count is zero.

Comment: Bethony, I noticed a small typo in the WHILE clause which has been adjusted. If you still require the status' when their count is 0 then remove all the references to @count_xxxxx > 0 There should be no requirement for `select distinct`

Answer (score 0):

I don’t believe you need a cursor for this (although it might be more efficient to use one). This gives you what you need, I think.

```
WITH Pnumbered AS (
  SELECT
    P.ID, P.status, P.times, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY P.ID, P.status
      ORDER BY P.times
    ) AS rn
  FROM Patient_Table AS P
), PA AS (
   SELECT
    P.ID, P.status, P.times
  FROM Patient_Table AS P
  WHERE P.status = 'Patient Arrive'
), Enough AS (
  SELECT PA.ID, S.status, S.statusseq, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY PA.ID, S.status
      ORDER BY PA.times
    ) AS rn FROM PA
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 'Patient Arrive',1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Patient Prepped',2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Patient Leave',3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Patient Return',4 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Patient Ready',5 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Patient Discharged',6
  ) AS S(status,statusseq)
)

SELECT
  Enough.ID, COALESCE(Pnumbered.status, Enough.status) as status, COALESCE(Pnumbered.times,'No Data Provided') AS times
FROM Pnumbered
RIGHT OUTER JOIN Enough
ON Pnumbered.ID = Enough.ID
AND Pnumbered.status = Enough.status
AND Pnumbered.rn = Enough.rn
ORDER BY ID, statusseq
```

The idea is as follows: Create a table with each patient `ID` and each `status` copied as many times as there are 'Arrive' rows for that `ID`, and number the copies. Also number the rows of the `Patient_Data` table that have the same `(ID, status)` in order by time. Finally, outer-join these two tables, so you get the right number of copies of each `(ID,status)`, and replace the `NULL` you get from unmatched rows in the outer join with 'Data Not Provided'. (The unmatched rows will be those with a given `ID` and `status` that exceed the number of actual rows for that `(ID,status)` in the `Patient_Data` table.

If you create a `Statuses` table for what I’ve derived as `S(status,statusseq)`, the query will look a bit simpler.

Here’s the output:

```
ID          status             times
----------- ------------------ -------------------
123666      Patient Arrive     20180606 10:52
123666      Patient Arrive     20180606 11:21
123666      Patient Arrive     20180606 11:45
123666      Patient Prepped    20180606 10:52
123666      Patient Prepped    20180606 11:45
123666      Patient Prepped    No Data Provided
123666      Patient Leave      20180606 10:52
123666      Patient Leave      No Data Provided
123666      Patient Leave      No Data Provided
123666      Patient Return     No Data Provided
123666      Patient Return     20180606 10:55
123666      Patient Return     20180606 12:30
123666      Patient Ready      20180606 12:45
123666      Patient Ready      No Data Provided
123666      Patient Ready      No Data Provided
123666      Patient Discharged No Data Provided
123666      Patient Discharged No Data Provided
123666      Patient Discharged 20180606 12:45
123667      Patient Arrive     20180607 10:52
123667      Patient Prepped    No Data Provided
123667      Patient Leave      No Data Provided
123667      Patient Return     No Data Provided
123667      Patient Ready      No Data Provided
123667      Patient Discharged No Data Provided
```